# iOS 11 navigation bar weird behaviour with search controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

**General**

I've been working on an application which was not touched since the release of iOS 11. Search controller in navigation bar was always the core part of it, this controller was used as a title view to always appear at the top of the screen.

**Current Status**

Some research lead me to the point where I could manage to replace the old `navigationItem.titleView` with the standard `navigationItem.searchController` property so iOS can handle everything related to the transition between views and so on.

[image: Navigation Bar Weird Behavior]
.

**Problem**

This is the point where I got stuck because there is a huge glitch while going from "A" view controller to "B". I don't want to use large titles, the best solution would be to completely remove title and display only the search bar as the content of the navigation bar but unfortunately I couldn't get to that point.

**Edit:** These view's are embedded in a tab bar controller as well.

**Search Controller setup code in `viewDidLoad()`**:

```
// Initialize search controller and set its important attributes
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

// Set placeholder text
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = searchBarPlaceholder
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = .search

// Replace title view with search bar
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
    searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately.